# Unlimited Guessing Game Java 0-100 need print out how many guesses it took when the number is guessed correctly

Tags: java, max, min

I need to produce either a Scanner variable, or something else at the last print statement when the user inputs the last number. I have tried implementing several variations of println statements to add in and nothing has worked. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create a random number generator

    Random random = new Random();

    // Use Scanner for getting input from user

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Use the random generator to 
    // pick a number between 0 and 99 (inclusive)

    int number = random.nextInt(10);
    int guess = -1;
    int count = 0;

    // Loop until the user has guessed the number

    while (guess != number) {

        // Prompt the user for their next guess

        System.out.print("Guess a number between 0-100: P.S. I will tell you if you are too low, or too high. Good Luck  \n  ");

        // Read the users guess

        guess = scanner.nextInt();
        count++;

        // Check if the guess is high, low or correct

        if (guess < number) {

            // Guess is too low

            System.out.println("Too low, please try again");

        } else if (guess > number) {

            // Guess is too high

            System.out.println("Too high, please try again");

        } else {

            // Guess is correct !!

            System.out.println("Correct, the number was " + number + ". You needed " + count + " times");
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: *"I need to produce either a Scanner variable, or something else at the last print statement when the user inputs the last number"* -- Care to elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Is this a Langara CS assignment? I'm pretty sure I had this exact assignment in CPSC 1060 or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a counter variable before the `while` loop

```
int count = 0;
```

Increase it after each new guess

```
guess = scanner.nextInt();
count++;
```

Print it when user enters correct answer

```
System.out.println("Correct, the number was " + number + ". You needed " + count + " times");
```

Comment: Thank you. I will update the doe to work correctly now.